# Set list as vertex/edge attribute

Tags: python, igraph

I started using igraph for my B.Sc. thesis but i'm struggling when i try to assign a list as an attribute of a vertex.

Here's what i tried:

```
 self.network.vs(node)[propertyName] = [0, value]
```

where `network` is my graph and `node` the name of the vertex.

When i try to access the elements i got an error (out of bounce) because the length of the list returned is 0.

How can I assign a list as a property of a vertex?

Comment: I am not familiar with igraph but have you tried using networkx? Networkx makes it very simple to add attributes to nodes, plus in Networkx you can save your graph in a number of formats that can be opened in igraph (I checked).

Comment: since my complete code wraps around igraph I would basically have to start from scratch. But thanks for the suggestion; It looks like it could be better suited for my use case anyway

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you assign a list to a vertex property it is typically distributed over the vertices even though you give a specific vertex number. You have to specify that it is a list for a specific vertex. Such as the following.

```
self.network.vs(node)[propertyName] = [[0, value]]
```